# Binomial Random variable. An At-least Question

Tags: probability

## Question

The probability that a favorite in a horse race win money (1st, 2nd or 3rd place) is `0.67`
 In the next 5 races, what is the probability that the favorite  finishes in the money **at least four times**.

---

## My attempt

I'm going to find the probability of the horse not finishing in money 0-time, 1-times, 2-times and 3-times. And then take the complement.:
$$1 - [P(X=0) + P(X=1) + P(X=2) + P(X=3) ]$$
This way I can find the probability of the horse finishing at least 4 times. i.e (X=4 and X=5). I know this is a longer way but I wanted to practice the complement rule in the "at-least" question. Here is my working:
$$1-[(5c0)(0.33)^5 + (5c1)(0.67)^1(0.33)^4 + (5c2)(0.67)^2(0.33)^3 + (5c3)(0.67)^3(0.33)^2 ] = 0.4675$$

---

I want to make sure if I have got the correct answer. So have I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is the same but I have used another method
First of all I have found the possibility where the horse win 4 races
$ 0.67^{4}*0.33^{1}\approx 0.0665 $
But this is one case: if you want find all the possible case you must do this:
$ \binom{5}{4}*0.67^{4}*0.33^{1}\approx0.3325  $
These are all the possible case where the horse win 4 races. But you ask **at least** 4 races, so you have to add $ 0.67^{5}$(the horse win 5 races).
The final result it will be
$P(x \geqslant 4)= \left (\binom{5}{4}*0.67^{4}*0.33^{1}\right )+\left( 0.67^{5} \right )\approx 0,4675  $

Answer (score 2):

@Krimson;

You can also use a generating function. Sort of overkill but I like them.

$\left(\frac{67 w}{100}+\frac{33}{100}\right)^5 $

This can be expanded by the binomial theorem or if you have access to some computing power or Wolfram.

$ \frac{39135393}{10000000000}+\frac{79456707 w}{2000000000}+\frac{161321193 w^2}{1000000000}+\frac{327530907 w^3}{1000000000}+\frac{664986993 w^4}{2000000000}+\frac{1350125107 w^5}{10000000000}$

We take the last two terms the ones with w^4 and w^5 because those represent 4 wins and 5 wins.

$ \frac{664986993 w^4}{2000000000}+\frac{1350125107 w^5}{10000000000}$

substitute 1 to eliminate the variable.

$ P(\text{4 or more wins })=\frac{664986993 }{2000000000}+\frac{1350125107 }{10000000000}=0.4675060072 $